# ORA-01858 and can not find where

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a quiet longish SQL query and for some customers it will result in a ORA-01858 error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected
> *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
> incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
> required by the format model.
> *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
> elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

I can not find the row where the error happens.

Is there a way to show me which row is faulty?
Is this error only appearing when using the *to_date* function or could it be any other function?

It is a Oracle SQL server 12.1.0.2.0 and I am using the Oracle SQL Developer 19.4.0.354

Thanks for your help

Comment: Without seeing SQL query we cannot comment anything.

Comment: Try reducing the statement as much as possible while the error still occurs and post that statement here. We cannot find an error in a statement we do not know. With the current information we may only give you generic advice, which the error description already does.